# Javascript. Как вернуть переменную из функции?

Tags: javascript

Имеется несколько кнопок(*input type="button"*), на которые повешен объект событий **event.target** ,a конкретнее **onclick**.
Когда происходит клик по одной из кнопок, в функцию **handler();** передается значение(*value="..."*) **input'a**(*btn1, btn2 или btn3*) и сохраняется в переменную **inpValue**.
Вопрос: как вытащить переменную **inpValue** за пределы функции **handler();** ?

```js
let btns = document.getElementById('buttons');

btns.addEventListener('click', handler);

function handler(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  let inpValue = target.value;
  return function () {
    return inpValue;
  }
}

let theInputValue = handler();
console.log(theInputValue());
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="btn1">
    <input type="button" value="btn2">
    <input type="button" value="btn3">
</div>
```

В консоль выдает такую ошибку: **TypeError: e is undefined**
Тут судя по всему **handler();** требует аргумент при вызове через переменную **theInputValue**, но что засунуть туда я не знаю

Comment: вообще непонятно что ты делаешь и для чего.

Comment: @Grundy Я изучаю замыкание! Не получается получить значение inpValue вне функции. Вроде вопрос понятный)

Comment: inpValue - локальная переменная, извне ты ее никак не получишь. А так как речь вообще идет про обработчики события - смотри вопрос-дубликат.

Comment: @Grundy то-есть значение переменной я смогу получить только если я её  сделаю глобальной ?как раз я не хочу этого делать

Comment: Нет. Прочитай ответы на вопрос-дубликат.

Comment: @Grundy, ты точно тем дубликатом закрыл?))

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, определенно! В обработчике события он заполняет переменную, и хочет получить значение этой переменной.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Есть варианты?

Comment: @Denisoed, ну вообще да. Мне кажется здесь дубликат связан очень косвенно и разбираясь в нем Вы просто сломаете себе мозг на ровном месте. Сформулируйте русским языком что делает ваша функця handler =)

Comment: @Denisoed, потому что по вашему вопросу не оч понятно _что_ именно Вы не понимаете. Возможно проблемы с которой связан дубликат. Если да, то пока читайте до "проблема макаронного кода", дальше не читайте, только запутаетесь.

Comment: и я бы советовал вам задачу чуть подробить для понимания. Если хотите разобраться в замыканиях, постарайтесь одновременно не использовать события и наоборот

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму"Этот код является учебным) сразу говорю! и так, на странице есть три инпута со значением btn1, btn2, btn3. Когда я нажимаю на один из них, значение этого инпута обрабатывается обьектом событий(EVENT.TARGET) и вызывает функцию, в которую передается значение(то-есть value=" ") нажатого инпута и это значение записывается в переменную(так же не важно в какую). После чего мне нужно вывести эту переменную за пределы функции. и как я понимаю это можно сделать через замыкание

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Записываю в новую переменную(снаружи) то что мне вернула функция. Вызываю эту переменную, допустим console.log(a()); И переменная **a** от меня требует аргумент(то есть event.target)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму В коде выше все видно

Comment: @Denisoed, в коде выше-то все видно, видно то что вы придумали себе какую-то странную задачу и странное решение в которых сами и запутались) И ответом на ваш вопрос по хорошему должно быть не точечное исправление странного решения странной задачи а какие-то наводящие вопросы чтобы Вы поняли что это странно и делают не то и не так) Но у меня к сожалению вот прям ща нет на это времени

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму И на этом спасибо =)